# How to save a string from a file into a variable in bash

Tags: bash, unix, variables, cat

I am trying to make a script that will ask you for a path to several files when you set it up and when you run the actual script, it reads the path from a file that you created earlier. I can make the file, I just need to know how to take that path and use it in the current script.

ex. 
Settings
    `/home/user/launcher`
Launcher
    `cat Settings`
    `read PathToLaunchers`

```
cd \$PathToLaunchers
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
read pathToFiles
for f in $pathToFiles
do
    cat $f
done
```

I am just printing the contexts of each file entered in `pathToFiles`. You can replace `cat` command with the command you are interested.

If `pathToFiles` has only one line (i.e. only one filename), then you dnt need the `for`  loop and just use `cat $pathToFiles`

Comment: I have this
    `read PathToLaunchers`
    `cat Settings`
    `cd \$PathToLaunchers`
But it is not saving it to the variable, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: you should use `cd $PathToLaunchers` Putting a `\`` escapes the `$` sign which does not dereference the variable.

Comment: If you are interested in appending \ before a variable, try this `temp="\\"$pathToLaunchers` and then use `cd $temp`